# Redirect routing in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I have a main project with some controllers, e.g. HomeController containing an action "Index". This action is reached by www.mysite.com/home/index.

Then I have **another project called "plugin"**, which is referenced within the main project. 
There is a controller, e.g. **CustomerController**. An action within this controller contains a **routing attribute "[Route("edit")]"**.
This action is reached by **www.mysite.com/customer/edit**. But I want that this action can be reached by **www.mysite.com/plugin/customer/edit** containing the name of the project (or another name).

How can I do this *without setting routing attribute for every controller* in my "plugin" project?

Btw.. I'm using NopCommerce 4.1 if it's necessary to know..

Comment: Which web server are you using? IIS? Have you considered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is scenario for Areas.

1) Inside your plugin create folder structure

```
Areas
..Plugin
....Controllers
....Views
```

2) Inside controllers create base plugin controller "PluginController" where you set Area attribute

```
[Area("Plugin")]
public class PluginController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

3) Make all your plugin controllers inherit from `PluginController`

```
public class CustomerController : PluginController
{
    ...
}
```

4) Add support for areas into route builder

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "defaultWithArea",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Now all actions inside your plugin will require **www.mysite.com/plugin/** ...

I'll also note that If you wish to retrieve action urls from outside the plugin you need to specify area of the controller like so:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer", new { Area = "Plugin" })
```